# My Encryption Decryption Algorithm

Tags: java, cryptography

I have been trying for so long to code an encryption/decryption algorithm using the modulus operator. Basically my code does a basic mathematical operation on given text and key then do a modulus 255 as in 255 ASCII characters. But I was never able to successfully reverse a modulus operator. I have finally programmed something that seems to work pretty well. It even encrypts then decrypts binary data to back to original.

I know it's never a wise idea to write your own encryption algorithm but I was just amazed with what I have come up with and would like to share it with critics to give me their opinions. Opinions on whether it is a viable encryption algorithm or really weak etc.

So here's the code. I appreciate any feedback.

By the way I called it MyCrypt. Pretty original name :)

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] text, String key)
{
    byte[] b = new byte[text.length];

    int keyIntTotal = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < key.length(); p++)
    {
        keyIntTotal += key.charAt(p);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        int alpha = text[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < key.length(); j++)
        {
            alpha += (text.length + (int)key.charAt(j) * (i ^ j) * keyIntTotal) % 255;
        }

        b[i] = (byte) (alpha % 256);
    }

    return b;
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String key)
{
    byte[] b = new byte[cipherText.length];

    int keyIntTotal = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < key.length(); p++)
    {
        keyIntTotal += key.charAt(p);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length; i++)
    {
        int alpha = cipherText[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < key.length(); j++)
        {
            alpha -= (cipherText.length + (int) key.charAt(j) * (i ^ j) * keyIntTotal) % 255;
        }
        alpha *= -1;

        b[i] = (byte) ((256 - alpha) % 256);
    }

    return b;
}
```

Comment: There are 128 ASCII characters, not 255.  Also, it appears to be much less efficient than most stream ciphers, as the work done is O(n·m) (where n is message length and m is key length) rather than the more usual O(n).

Comment: Well, 255 different bytes i meant.. Extended ASCII

Answer (score 1):

> whether it is a viable encryption algorithm

It is not.

Rewrite the encryption (pretty mechanically) as

```
    int alpha = text[i];
    int alpha_shift = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < key.length(); j++)
    {
        alpha_shift += (text.length + (int)key.charAt(j) * (i ^ j) * keyIntTotal) % 255;
    }

    b[i] = (byte) ((alpha + alpha_shit) % 256);
```

and observe that `alpha_shift` only depends on the character's position `i`. It means that an attacker doesn't need to know the key. It only need to ask the victim to encrypt few plaintexts. *Very few*, because there is no [avalanche effect](https://www.cryptovision.com/en/glossary/avalanche-effect).

---

For a proper review, **no naked loops**. The shift computation shall be factored out into a function:

```
    int alpha = text[i];
    b[i] = (byte) ((alpha + alpha_shift(key, i)) % 256;
```

Comment: I appreciate your warnings and clarifications. I will consider your advise .Thank you so much.